# Insert image popup showing blank in magento backend

Tags: magento-1.9

In my static block page i can't able to add image if i click inser image it showing blank page

[image]

Comment: Use firebug console to see and find out what is going with AJAX request/response.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, It would be great and very helpful if you can share the solution.